# Union of simple types in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have to make a simple element that can be either be an integer or a date. The element I have to use is `score`.

I've looked at a few links but I don't really understand.

eg: [how to define xsd element with multiple option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987726/how-to-define-xsd-element-with-multiple-option)

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_simple.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`xsd:union`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#derivation-by-union) to create new type consisting of the *union* of other `xs:integer` and `xs:date`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="score">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:union memberTypes="xs:integer xs:date"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: My understanding of unions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699121/what-is-purpose-of-xsdunion-in-xml-schema-xsd, is that the union includes both members. The original poster here asked for either one or the other, but not both. Most likely I don't properly understand unions in XSDs. Hence my question.

Comment: @MikeStoddart: Yes, unions are in the set theoretical sense, but does that matter here?   Do you know of a value that would qualify as both an integer and a date such that your or OP's *either* constraint would not be met anyway?